# How to use localization in Blade tag templates?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

**1st question:**

I've inserted the localization in many types of texts and things, but I don't know how to import it into in the following forms:

```
  {{ Form::label('name', 'here') }}
  {{ Form::text('name', null, array('placeholder' => 'here')) }}
  {{ Form::submit('here', array('class' => 'btn btn-success')) }}
  {{ Form::button('here', array('class' => 'btn btn-default')) }}
```

I want it to be in the form label 'here' and in the placeholder of the text 'here'.

**2nd question:**

I am not allowed to insert it with links in my language file: `text here blah blah <a href="{{ URL::to('text') }}">BLAH</a>?`

Is there anyway to insert it with links?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Solved the 1st question, only couldn't figure out the placeholder. If anyone could help that and the 2nd question..

Comment: Just replace `'here'` with `Lang::get('here')` for both questions.

Answer (score 14):

Supposing that your messages are stored in `app/lang/en/message.php` you can use the same way for all your cases:

In Blade template:

```php
{{ Form::label('name', Lang::get('message.key')) }}

{{ Form::text('name', null, array('placeholder' => Lang::get('message.key'))) }}

{{ Form::submit(Lang::get('message.key'), array('class' => 'btn btn-success')) }}
```

In HTML tag mixed with some Blade expression:

```html
<a href="{{ URL::to(Lang::get('message.key')) }}">BLAH</a>
```

Comment: You can also use `trans()` helper function which wraps `Lang::get()`. More info http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#strings

Comment: @Rubens Mariuzzo I don't think we understand eachother. I want the text be like: `'message' => 'There are no messages, would you like to <a href="{{ URL::to('messages/create') }}>create one?</a>` in my language file, not to retrieve.

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo anything?

Comment: I was thinking about a better way to do so... but I just think that is weird to store bits of code inside a localized message. In any case, why you don't use placeholder? So you can replace them with the generated URL.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use localization in Blade templates using strictly Blade syntax.
Given that you have a message in your `/app/lang/en/messages.php` that corresponds to the key "message_key", you can do :

```
@lang('messages.message_key')
```

to render the message in the locale that your application is configured to use.

Comment: For a specific translation pls make sure to use these arguments below @lang('translationfile.mylabel', array(), 'en')

Answer (score 5):

So, The answers for both of your questions are:-

1)  {{ Form::label('name', 'here') }}

```
  Here, you need to change the "here" text hence laravel localization method can be used.For eg:-
{{ Form::label('name', '__("Here")' }} or
{{ Form::label('name', '__('message.here') }}.
```

2)< a href="{{ URL::to('text') }}">BLAH< /a>

Here, you need to change the label instead of link.

```
< a href="URL::to('text') ">{{__('message.BLAH')}}< /a>.
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible answer to your second question:

You could set up a language file `resources/lang/en/page.php` like this:

```
return [
    'sentence' => 'A sentence with a :link in the middle.',
    'link_text' => 'link to a another page'
];
```

And use it in a Blade template like this:

```
{!! trans('page.sentence', [
    'link' => '<a href="/">' . trans('page.link_text') . '</a>'
]) !!}}
```

The result would be:

A sentence with a [link to a another page](https://stackoverflow.com/) in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplest which works for me !

```
{!! Form::label('title', trans('users.addNewRecordsNameFieldLabel'),['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
```

I feel, already blade parsing is started the moment {!! or {{ is started

Answer (score 1):

You alse can use __() method

{{ __('app.name') }}