# How to translate strings from jquery to blade on laravel

Tags: php, jquery, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have two separated files on my laravel, a index.blade.php and a .js file.
On the blade I have a string, something like this:

```
<p id="currentMessage" class="bold-700"></p>
```

In my JS I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#currentMessage').text("@lang('hello'));
});
```

Seems like it doesn't translate on runtime and I can't inject a text and wait it to be translated, but there is any way to get the string translated on jquery before sending or something else to do the trick?

Comment: You're missed to write your file name like this: @lang('<YOUR_FILE_NAME>.hello')     See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220755/how-to-use-localization-in-blade-tag-templates#answer-29752995)

Comment: @boolfalse mmm no, this is for blade only, i'm talking about sending from JS to blade...

Comment: Aw, sorry.. if you want to write that in .js, as far as I know there is no traditional way for use that in .js    By the way I knew that you can configure your .htaccess to enable php interpretation from .js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can inject the translation from blade to javascript this way:

```
<script>
var translations = {
   hello: "@lang('hello')",
   goodbye: "@lang('goodbye')",
   ...
};
</script>
```

Then in your js file,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#currentMessage').text(translations.hello);
});
```

Comment: Well it could work but having to rewrite all my sentences its a bit annoying

Comment: you can use a slug function to create slugs for each sentence. and then loop over it. And you can create a separate "cached" blade file building this structure to keep the translations. There's no other way I guess than this or creating a dynamic js file with php. `<script src='translations.php' type='text/javascript'></script>`. But still you would need to create this structure to pass to a JS file.